# Using Javascript objects, calling their keys and comparing them

Tags: javascript, iteration

If I have two separate objects in Javascript:

```
test_object_1 = {name: "tom", age: 22, occupation: "bus driver", favorite_color: "blue"};
test_object_2 = {name: "howard", age: 22, favorite_color: "blue", occupation: "dog walker"};
```

How would I go about comparing seeing if there was two matching key, value pairs. I would prefer if it was multiple functions, I am trying to do it in the most understandable way possible. (I would prefer not to use .hasOwnProperty because I do not yet understand it, if used please explain its use explicitly)

It should return `true` for both `age` and `favorite_color`.

Comment: Loop over the keys, reference both objects, see if that key matches.

Comment: Instead of deciding not to use a feature because you do not understand it, why don't you learn it?

Comment: I am trying to, but can't figure it out. Which is why the other answer on Stack overflow which my question is marked to duplicate uses doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect this! @torazaburo

Comment: Do you want to match where both objects have the same key with the same value as well, or just that the key exists on both?